# Sinatra::Synchrony with websocket

Tags: concurrency, websocket, sinatra, eventmachine, em-synchrony

Given [Sinatra::Synchrony](https://github.com/kyledrake/sinatra-synchrony#readme) is using [EM-Synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony#em-synchrony) "collection of convenience classes and primitives to help untangle evented code" so that you can write "fast, highly concurrent web applications with no callbacks (just by developing as if you were writing a normal Sinatra web application, and using non-blocking libraries)"..

How would one implement a Sinatra::Synchrony "hello world" app which uses websock protocol with no callbacks ?

To put it in another way: are Sinatra::Synchrony and EM-Synchrony also covering the websocket part ? I could not find enough documentation on this... Can someone give me a couple of lines of code to start ?

Thanks